# Is it possible to create shapefiles in ArcGIS and convert into SpatialNET?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, convert, autocad

I'm looking at the prospect of working for a client who has implemented a SpatialNET solution. I have never used SpatialNET and primarily have experience with ESRI and Autodesk products. The client and Synchronoss (who owns SpatialNET) have both told me that the only solution is to purchase a SpatialNET license and VPN into their database. When I asked them about creating files in AutoCAD or ArcMap, they said it would not work. I find it hard to believe that the SpatialNET system is completely incompatible with them, especially considering that SpatialNET appears to be based off of AutoCAD. Anyone here have experience with this product?

Comment: do they read kml ?

Answer (score 1):

Technically yes, it is possible. However there are no packaged tools with SpatialNET to do so, so if you were to do it (which I would advise against in the strongest terms) the method would be to build the data in ArcGIS and then bulk-load it to the Oracle Spatial back-end of the SpatialNET instance. (There is also a Python API that you could use to build a script to load data, but that's harder again.)

But I can see why both Synchronoss and the client have said no as it makes it very easy to break things. My advise would be to do as the client requested - purchase the license and VPN to their database (if nothing else with the AutoCAD experience it shouldn't be too hard to pick up SpatialNET).